# Merge two DataFrames with overlapping MultiIndex columns

Tags: pandas, merge, multi-index

I'm trying to find a simple way to merge two MultiIndex dataframes together in a way that adds new columns and merges existing. For example if I had two data frames

```
d1_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B",], ["1", "2"]])
d1_index = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-5", freq="D")
d1 = pd.DataFrame(random.rand(5, 4), columns=d1_columns, index=d1_index)

print(d1)


                 A                   B          
                   1         2         1         2
2020-01-01  0.381909  0.487480  0.389250  0.853449
2020-01-02  0.752374  0.508806  0.491892  0.786918
2020-01-03  0.019655  0.537763  0.263242  0.378302
2020-01-04  0.460276  0.227113  0.423472  0.514639
2020-01-05  0.046673  0.864282  0.223340  0.929049

d2_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["B", "C"], ["1", "2"]])
d2_index = pd.date_range("2020-01-03", "2020-01-7", freq="D")
d2 = pd.DataFrame(random.rand(5, 4), columns=d2_columns, index=d2_index)

print(d2)

                   B                   C          
                   1         2         1         2
2020-01-03  0.495979  0.888207  0.776861  0.531693
2020-01-04  0.408030  0.545351  0.452913  0.768284
2020-01-05  0.374996  0.593571  0.925979  0.398629
2020-01-06  0.085565  0.845354  0.792325  0.501057
2020-01-07  0.780985  0.390948  0.731769  0.488155
```

If I want to merge them I get the overlapping columns seperated, while the new columns work fine:

```
df = d1.merge(d2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer")

print(df)

                   A                 B_x                 B_y            \
                   1         2         1         2         1         2   
2020-01-01  0.381909  0.487480  0.389250  0.853449       NaN       NaN   
2020-01-02  0.752374  0.508806  0.491892  0.786918       NaN       NaN   
2020-01-03  0.019655  0.537763  0.263242  0.378302  0.495979  0.888207   
2020-01-04  0.460276  0.227113  0.423472  0.514639  0.408030  0.545351   
2020-01-05  0.046673  0.864282  0.223340  0.929049  0.374996  0.593571   
2020-01-06       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.085565  0.845354   
2020-01-07       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.780985  0.390948   

                   C            
                   1         2  
2020-01-01       NaN       NaN  
2020-01-02       NaN       NaN  
2020-01-03  0.776861  0.531693  
2020-01-04  0.452913  0.768284  
2020-01-05  0.925979  0.398629  
2020-01-06  0.792325  0.501057  
2020-01-07  0.731769  0.488155
```

Is there a simple way to have the overlapping columns merge so that new data is added to the existing columns (it doesn't matter if it overwrites previous data), so the output looks like this?

```
                   A                 B                     C          
                   1         2         1         2         1         2
2020-01-01  0.633182  0.335651  0.072520  0.578472       NaN       NaN
2020-01-02  0.785482  0.562421  0.658556  0.557171       NaN       NaN
2020-01-03  0.755049  0.575611  0.592934  0.735094  0.647117  0.306296
2020-01-04  0.035943  0.792211  0.002617  0.159366  0.320691  0.825184
2020-01-05  0.932623  0.643129  0.778002  0.581527  0.718405  0.289289
2020-01-06       NaN       NaN  0.085565  0.845354  0.012412  0.960234
2020-01-07       NaN       NaN  0.780985  0.390948  0.444406  0.210821
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want

```
df = d1.combine_first(d2)
```

or

```
df = d2.combine_first(d1)
```

depending on which frame's values shall be preferred.